# INDIRECT("R[-1]",false) localisation

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you use this kind of reference in another language?

It's giving me a "#reference!" error in german ("#Bezug!").

I tried `INDIREKT("R[-1]",false)`, `INDIREKT("Z[-1]",false)`, `INDIREKT("S[-1]",false)` but nothing works.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27318078/5164855) should allow you to find the correct string. I don't have a non-English version of Excel to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too don't have a non-English version of Excel to test this on.  [This web page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_officeinsider-mso_win10-msoinsider_excel/indirect-function-is-broken-at-least-for-excel-in/1fcbcf20-a103-4172-abf1-2c0dfe848e60) says that it was broken for non-English versions of Excel 2016.
[image: Localised Excel]
It appears German got doubly-cheated, as it doesn't even work for R1C1 notation like it does for French, meaning no hack workaround.

The original post also states a few different build numbers, as does the moderator stating it should be fixed in a later build:

✅ 16.0.6741.2063
❌ 16.0.7167.2040
❌ 16.0.7167.2047
✅ 16.0.7341.2032 (should be fixed)

Any chance you're in that bad-zone of builds?

Edit: Also in the original post you're using `false` whereas the localised version (according to the linked page and image) is `falsch`.  The [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) says if the argument is "TRUE or omitted", I'm guessing an invalid argument also counts as `true`.

Comment: You're lightning fast, I always knew that the german version seemed more bugged than the english one.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Honestly I was just curious!  I didn't realise they localised the function names and cell reference system.  Did you fall into that tiny bracket of broken builds, or is it broken again?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Or (I just noticed this) was it because you're using `false` and the localised version is `falsch`?

Comment: I honestly haven't tested yet, it's not really a hard issue because you do have alternatives, but the syntax is just so cool with r[-1], that I wanted to make it work.
I'll look into it this week and update my version, also the typo was only in the question because I typed it manually, otherwise if you write false instead of falsch it will probably not even let you press enter without throwing you the old "something isn't right with your formula"-dialogue.